# Linq order by, group by and order by each group?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create the following query: group grades by student name, order each student group by grades, and order groups by max grade in each group.

So it will look like this:

```
A 100
A 80
B 80
B 50
B 40
C 70
C 30
```

I created the following query:

```
StudentsGrades.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
    .OrderBy(studentGradesGroup => studentGradesGroup.Max(student => student.Grade));
```

But that returns `IEnumerable` `IGrouping`, and I have no way to sort the list inside, unless I do that in another `foreach` query and add the results to a different list using `AddRange`.

Is there a prettier way to do that?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Sure:

```
var query = grades.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
                  .Select(group => 
                        new { Name = group.Key,
                              Students = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade) })
                  .OrderBy(group => group.Students.First().Grade);
```

Note that you can get away with just taking the first grade within each group after ordering, because you already know the first entry will have the highest grade.

Then you could display them with:

```
foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group: {0}", group.Name);
    foreach (var student in group.Students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", student.Grade);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no Key property on that var group variable.

Comment: Thank you! This is the finished query - studentGrades.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
                  .Select(group => new { Students = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade) })
                  .OrderByDescending(group => group.Students.First().Grade)
                  .SelectMany(group => group.Students)

Answer (score 23):

The way to do it without projection:

```
StudentsGrades.OrderBy(student => student.Name).
ThenBy(student => student.Grade);
```

Comment: I think it's because while it would order the data as requested, it's by chance. The order of best performing students is also alphabetical. If you give Student C a grade of 90, they should appear above Student B. In this answer they wouldn't.

Answer (score 18):

I think you want an additional projection that maps each group to a sorted-version of the group:

```
.Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(student => student.Grade))
```

---

It also appears like you *might* want another flattening operation after that which will give you a sequence of students instead of a sequence of groups:

```
.SelectMany(group => group)
```

You can always collapse both into a *single* `SelectMany` call that does the projection and flattening together.

---

EDIT:
As Jon Skeet points out, there are certain inefficiencies in the overall query; the information gained from sorting each group is not being used in the ordering of the groups themselves. By moving the sorting of each group to come *before* the ordering of the groups themselves, the `Max` query can be dodged into a simpler `First` query.

Answer (score 6):

try this...

```
public class Student 
    {
        public int Grade { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name{0} : Grade{1}", Name, Grade);
        }
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      List<Student> listStudents = new List<Student>();
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 10, Name = "Pedro" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 10, Name = "Luana" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 10, Name = "Maria" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 11, Name = "Mario" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 15, Name = "Mario" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 10, Name = "Bruno" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 10, Name = "Luana" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 11, Name = "Luana" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 22, Name = "Maria" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 55, Name = "Bruno" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 77, Name = "Maria" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 66, Name = "Maria" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 88, Name = "Bruno" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 42, Name = "Pedro" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 33, Name = "Bruno" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 33, Name = "Luciana" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 17, Name = "Maria" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 25, Name = "Luana" });
      listStudents.Add(new Student() { Grade = 25, Name = "Pedro" });

      listStudents.GroupBy(g => g.Name).OrderBy(g => g.Key).SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade)).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do  like this :

```
     var _items = from a in StudentsGrades
                  group a by a.Name;

     foreach (var _itemGroup in _items)
     {
        foreach (var _item in _itemGroup.OrderBy(a=>a.grade))
        {
           ------------------------
           --------------------------
        }
     }
```