# LINQ to SQL - order by, group by and order by each group with skip and take

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

This is an extension of already answered question by Jon Skeet that you can [find here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013710/linq-order-by-group-by-and-order-by-each-group)

The desired result is following:

```
A 100
A 80
B 80
B 50
B 40
C 70
C 30
```

considering you have following class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

to get to the result (in ideal scenario) can be done with Jon Skeet's answer:

```
var query = grades.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
                  .Select(group => 
                        new { Name = group.Key,
                              Students = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade) })
                  .OrderBy(group => group.Students.FirstOrDefault().Grade);
```

However in my case I have to support paging in my query as well. This means performing **SelectMany()** and then do **Skip()** and **Take()**. But to do **Skip()** you have to apply **OrderBy()**. This is where my ordering breaks again as I need to preserve the order I get after **SelectMany()**.

How to achieve this?

```
var query = grades.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
                  .Select(group => 
                        new { Name = group.Key,
                              Students = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade) })
                  .OrderBy(group => group.Students.FirstOrDefault().Grade).SelectMany(s => s.Students).OrderBy(something magical that doesn't break ordering).Skip(s => skip).Take(t => take);
```

I know I could manually sort again the records when my query is materialised but I would like to avoid this and do all of it in one SQL query that is translated from LINQ.

Comment: @IvanStoev all good, no worries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take another approach using `Max` instead of ordering each group and taking the first value. After that you can order by max grade, name (in case two students have the same max grade) and grade:

```
var query = c.Customers
    .GroupBy(s => s.Name, (k, g) => g
        .Select(s => new { MaxGrade = g.Max(s2 => s2.Grade), Student = s }))
    .SelectMany(s => s)
    .OrderBy(s => s.MaxGrade)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Student.Name)
    .ThenByDescending(s => s.Student.Grade)
    .Select(s => s.Student)
    .Skip(toSkip)
    .Take(toTake)
    .ToList();
```

All these methods are supported by EF6 so you should get your desired result.

Comment: It's not gonna work as you have to have OrderBy before the Skip clause.

Comment: @JakubHolovsky and there is `OrderBy` before `Skip` but it doesn't have to be right before it. This restriction exists in SQL because for  `OFFSET FETCH` clause there must be `ORDER BY` before it and for the SQL translated from the above query it's true. Just test it. It's gonna work.

Comment: It's indeed working. Just a small correction - the first order (`.OrderBy(s => s.MaxGrade)`) must be descending.

Comment: Does work indeed, pretty amazing, thanks. Hope someone will understand it someday when they read it after me.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-index your list results and remove the index before returning.

```
var query = grades.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
       .Select(group => 
               new { Name = group.Key, 
                    Students = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade)
                   })
       .OrderBy(group => group.Students.FirstOrDefault().Grade)
       .SelectMany(s => s.Students)
       .Select((obj,index) => new {obj,index})
       .OrderBy(newindex => newindex.index)
       .Skip(s => skip).Take(t => take)
       .Select(final=> final.obj);
```

Comment: Will try tomorrow sounds promising hopefully it's gonna work with LINQ to SQL

Comment: No promises :)   You may need to consider a stored procedure to keep data transfer to a minimum.