# Indent chained method calls so they all start at the same position below each other

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Consider the following code formatting, taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013740/298288) answer.

```
var query = grades.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
                  .Select(group => 
                        new { Name = group.Key,
                              Students = group.OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade) })
                  .OrderBy(group => group.Students.First().Grade);
```

Note how the calls to `GroupBy`, `Select` and `OrderBy` all start exactly at the same position / are directly aligned below each other. How can I automatically format my code like this with either Visual Studio directly or using Resharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ReSharper, under *Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Tabs, Indents, Alignment -> Align multiline constructs*, check the *Chained method calls* box. It takes a bit of time but your really ought to have a thorough look through that *Options* dialogue.

[image]

Comment: ah great, thank you. I mixed this up with the Line breaks  - Wrap chained method calls option. And using the full options instead of Configure code style from the context menu provides the menu shown in your screenshot. didn't know that yet, helps a lot.

Comment: @John Is there an option to set it also in Visual Studio directly without ReSharper?